# How many Lists does SharePoint 2013 offer?

Tags: 2013, list

How many Lists does SharePoint 2013 offer? What's the definition of a SharePoint List?

Answer (score 5):

The base template types are found in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

A [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.aspx) is defined as:

> A list consists of items or rows, and columns or fields, that contain
>   data. The Items property returns the collection of items in the list,
>   and the Fields property returns the collection of fields in the list.

Easier to think of it as a table of tabular data versus a collection of files (document library).

Answer (score 2):

Lists are rich and flexible and have many built-in features that provide a robust way to store, share, and work with data.

A list is essentially a container where you put data. At the most basic level, a list resembles a table in a traditional SQL database, but in SharePoint, it is more complex than that. Unlike a traditional SQL database where the table defines what data you store in each row, each item in SharePoint has a schema defined by the type of content the item represents. You can also think of it as a spreadsheet with columns and rows.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-SharePoint-list

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-lists-0A1C3ACE-DEF0-44AF-B225-CFA8D92C52D7)

[Downloadable format](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2016-List-98e46150#content)

Answer (score 2):

**Number of lists in SharePoint :**

- Unfortunately , it's not mentioned at official MSDN Software boundaries and limits, but it's suggested to don't be more than `2000 lists per website` based on the response of Microsoft PFE.

For more details Check [Plan for software boundaries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx)

**List Definition :**

- Simply, List in SharePoint looks like Table in SQL in its structure,consists of rows and columns with specific limits so it is not like Table in its capability.

Check also [Comparing List and Library limits in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/05/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/)